# Nested Formik Validation

Tags: reactjs, formik

In my webapp, I'm trying to create a product that has options, and inside those options, there are sub-options.

The product is independent, but it has options (titles for the sub-options), and then the actual sub-options.

To better understand it, it looks like this

- Product

  - Option

    - Sub-option
    - Sub-option

The user can add as many options as he wants, as well as many sub-options.

Each option has a title
Each sub option has a title and a price

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Validation for number of sub-options (a.k.a "if you added an option, you need at least a sub-option under that option")
- Validation of sub-option title
- Validation of sub-option price

Currently, the only thing that works is the validation for the product details, but the option and sub-options validation is not working right.

The problems with the options and sub-options validation:

1. Despite filling the option title, I still get a "required"
2. In the console, I get a "you need at least one sub-option" (this lets me know that checking if an option lacks sub-options does not work)
3. The title of the sub-option is not being validated
4. The price of the sub-option seems to be getting passed to formik,
   but for some reason, I don't understand why it does while the title
   of the sub-option does not.

Here is my code (what I've tried so far):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ProductsTable from "./tables/ProductsTable";
import {
  IconArrowBack,
  IconBox,
  IconMinus,
  IconPlus,
  IconTrash,
} from "@tabler/icons-react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  Button,
  Chip,
  useDisclosure,
  ModalContent,
  ModalHeader,
  Input,
  Textarea,
  ModalFooter,
  Spinner,
  Switch,
} from "@nextui-org/react";
import { Formik, useFormik } from "formik";
import { toast, Toaster } from "sonner";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useQuery, useMutation, useQueryClient } from "react-query";
import * as api from "../api/services";

export default function Products() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([{ title: "", subOptions: [] }]);
  const [subOptions, setSubOptions] = useState([]);
  const [scrollBehavior, setScrollBehavior] = React.useState("inside");
  const [hasOptions, setHasOptions] = useState(true);

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  const { isOpen, onOpen, onOpenChange } = useDisclosure();

  const { shopId, categoryId } = useParams();

  const handleAddOption = () => {
    setOptions([...options, { title: "", subOptions: [] }]);
  };

  const handleRemoveOption = (optionIndex) => {
    const newOptions = [...options];
    newOptions.splice(optionIndex, 1);
    setOptions(newOptions);
  };

  const handleAddSubOption = (optionIndex) => {
    const newOptions = [...options];
    newOptions[optionIndex].subOptions.push("");
    setOptions(newOptions);
  };

  const handleRemoveSubOption = (optionIndex, subOptionIndex) => {
    const newOptions = [...options];
    newOptions[optionIndex].subOptions.splice(subOptionIndex, 1);
    setOptions(newOptions);
  };

  const handleOptionsMenu = () => {
    setHasOptions(!hasOptions);
  };

  const information = useQuery(["catInformation", shopId, categoryId], () =>
    api.fetchProducts(shopId, categoryId)
  );

  const addProduct = useMutation(
    (data) => {
      return api.storeProduct({ data, shopId, categoryId });
    },
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(["products"]);
        toast.success("Product has been created successfully");
      },
    }
  );

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      price: "",
      stock: "",
      description: "",
      picture: "",
      options: [{ title: "", subOptions: [] }],
    },
    validate: (values) => {
      const errors = {};

      // Validate name
      if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = "Required";
      } else if (values.name.length < 3) {
        errors.name = "Must be 3 characters or more";
      }

      // Validate price
      if (!values.price) {
        errors.price = "Required";
      } else if (isNaN(parseFloat(values.price))) {
        errors.price = "Price must be a decimal number";
      }

      // Validate stock
      if (!values.stock) {
        errors.stock = "Required";
      } else if (typeof values.stock !== "number") {
        errors.stock = "Stock must be a number";
      }

      // Validate description
      if (!values.description) {
        errors.description = "Required";
      }

      // Validate picture
      if (!values.picture) {
        errors.picture = "Required";
      }

      // Validate options
      if (!values.options || !values.options.length) {
        errors.options = "Must have at least one option";
      } else {
        values.options.forEach((option, index) => {
          if (!option.title) {
            errors.options = errors.options || [];
            errors.options[index] = errors.options[index] || {};
            errors.options[index].title = "Required";
          }

          if (!option.subOptions || !option.subOptions.length) {
            errors.options = [...(errors.options || [])];
            errors.options[index] = {
              ...errors.options[index],
              subOptions: "Must have at least one sub-option",
            };
          } else {
            option.subOptions.forEach((subOption, subIndex) => {
              if (!subOption.title) {
                errors.options[index].subOptions =
                  errors.options[index].subOptions || [];
                errors.options[index].subOptions[subIndex] =
                  errors.options[index].subOptions[subIndex] || {};
                errors.options[index].subOptions[subIndex].title = "Required";
              }

              if (!subOption.price) {
                errors.options = [...(errors.options || [])];
                errors.options[index] = { ...errors.options[index] };
                errors.options[index].subOptions = [
                  ...(errors.options[index].subOptions || []),
                ];
                errors.options[index].subOptions[subIndex] = {
                  ...errors.options[index].subOptions[subIndex],
                  price: "Required",
                };
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }

      return errors;
    },
    onSubmit: async (data) => {
      // addProduct.mutate(data, shopId, categoryId);
      console.log(data);
    },
  });

  console.log(formik.errors);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <Button
          className="bg-slate-500 text-white rounded-full"
          onClick={() => navigate(-1)}
        >
          <IconArrowBack /> Go back
        </Button>
      </div>
      <div className="col-span-2 flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
        <h1 className="text-3xl text-black-300 font-bold pt-3 mb-5">
          {information.isLoading ? (
            <>Loading...</>
          ) : (
            <>Products in "{information.data.category}"</>
          )}
        </h1>
        <Button className="bg-deep-green text-white" onPress={onOpen}>
          Add a product
        </Button>
      </div>
      <ProductsTable />
      <Modal
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
        size={`${hasOptions ? "3xl" : ""}`}
        scrollBehavior={scrollBehavior}
      >
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <ModalContent className="p-1">
            {(onClose) => (
              <>
                <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1">
                  <div className="flex">
                    <div className={`${hasOptions ? "w-1/2" : ``}`}>
                      Add a product
                    </div>
                    {hasOptions ? (
                      <div className="w-1/2">Add Options</div>
                    ) : (
                      <></>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                  <div className={`${hasOptions ? "flex" : ``}`}>
                    <div className={`${hasOptions ? "w-1/2 pr-5" : ``}`}>
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        label="Name"
                        name="name"
                        aria-label="name"
                        placeholder="Ex: Box of light bulbs"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        className="mb-3"
                      />
                      {formik.errors.name ? (
                        <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                          {formik.errors.name}
                        </p>
                      ) : null}
                      <Input
                        type="text"
                        label="Price"
                        placeholder="0.00"
                        name="price"
                        aria-label="price"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        className="mb-3"
                        startContent={
                          <div className="pointer-events-none flex items-center">
                            <span className="text-default-400 text-small">
                              €
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        }
                      />
                      {formik.errors.price ? (
                        <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                          {formik.errors.price}
                        </p>
                      ) : null}
                      <Input
                        type="number"
                        label="Stock"
                        placeholder="0"
                        name="stock"
                        aria-label="stock"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        className="mb-3"
                        startContent={
                          <div className="pointer-events-none flex items-center">
                            <span className="text-default-400 text-small">
                              <IconBox size={16} />
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        }
                      />
                      {formik.errors.stock ? (
                        <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                          {formik.errors.stock}
                        </p>
                      ) : null}
                      <Textarea
                        label="Description"
                        labelPlacement="outside"
                        name="description"
                        aria-label="description"
                        placeholder="Enter your description"
                        className="max-w-lg mb-3"
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                      />
                      {formik.errors.description ? (
                        <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                          {formik.errors.description}
                        </p>
                      ) : null}
                      <h1 className="text-sm pl-1">Picture</h1>
                      <input
                        className="block text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 mb-3"
                        id="file_input"
                        type="file"
                        name="picture"
                        aria-label="picture"
                        onChange={(event) => {
                          formik.setFieldValue(
                            "picture",
                            event.target.files[0]
                          );
                        }}
                      />
                      <Chip color="default" className="mb-3">
                        PNG, JPG (MAX 2 MB)
                      </Chip>
                      {formik.errors.picture ? (
                        <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                          {formik.errors.picture}
                        </p>
                      ) : null}
                      <Switch
                        defaultSelected
                        onChange={() => handleOptionsMenu()}
                      >
                        This product has options
                      </Switch>
                    </div>
                    {hasOptions ? (
                      <div className="w-1/2">
                        {options.map((option, optionIndex) => (
                          <div
                            key={optionIndex}
                            style={{
                              display: "flex",
                              flexDirection: "column",
                              alignItems: "flex-end",
                            }}
                          >
                            <Input
                              type="text"
                              label="Title"
                              name="title"
                              aria-label="optionTitle"
                              placeholder="Ex: Size"
                              className="mb-2"
                              onChange={(e) => {
                                const newOptions = [...options];
                                newOptions[optionIndex].title = e.target.value;
                                setOptions(newOptions);
                              }}
                            />
                            {formik.errors.options &&
                            formik.errors.options[optionIndex] &&
                            formik.errors.options[optionIndex].title ? (
                              <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                                {formik.errors.options[optionIndex].title}
                              </p>
                            ) : null}
                            {option.subOptions.map((option, subOptionIndex) => (
                              <div className="flex justify-between items-center w-full gap-1 mb-3">
                                <Input
                                  key={subOptionIndex}
                                  type="text"
                                  label="Title"
                                  name={`options[${optionIndex}].subOptions[${subOptionIndex}].title`}
                                  aria-label="title"
                                  placeholder="Ex: Medium"
                                  variant="underlined"
                                  onChange={(e) => {
                                    const newOptions = [...options];
                                    newOptions[optionIndex].subOptions[
                                      subOptionIndex
                                    ] = e.target.value;
                                    setOptions(newOptions);
                                  }}
                                />
                                {formik.errors.options &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex] &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex].subOptions &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex].subOptions[
                                  subOptionIndex
                                ] &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex].subOptions[
                                  subOptionIndex
                                ].title ? (
                                  <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                                    {
                                      formik.errors.options[optionIndex]
                                        .subOptions[subOptionIndex].title
                                    }
                                  </p>
                                ) : null}
                                <Input
                                  type="number"
                                  label="Additional cost"
                                  placeholder="0.00"
                                  variant="underlined"
                                  name={`options[${optionIndex}].subOptions[${subOptionIndex}].price`}
                                  aria-label="price"
                                  onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                  startContent={
                                    <div className="pointer-events-none flex items-center">
                                      <span className="text-default-400 text-small">
                                        €
                                      </span>
                                    </div>
                                  }
                                />
                                {formik.errors.options &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex] &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex].subOptions &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex].subOptions[
                                  subOptionIndex
                                ] &&
                                formik.errors.options[optionIndex].subOptions[
                                  subOptionIndex
                                ].price ? (
                                  <p className="text-danger-red text-sm pl-1">
                                    {
                                      formik.errors.options[optionIndex]
                                        .subOptions[subOptionIndex].price
                                    }
                                  </p>
                                ) : null}
                                <Button
                                  color="danger"
                                  size="sm"
                                  variant="light"
                                  onClick={() =>
                                    handleRemoveSubOption(
                                      optionIndex,
                                      subOptionIndex
                                    )
                                  }
                                >
                                  <IconTrash size={22} />
                                </Button>
                              </div>
                            ))}
                            <div className="flex flex-row gap-1">
                              <Button
                                color="danger"
                                variant="flat"
                                onClick={() => handleRemoveOption(optionIndex)}
                                className="mb-3"
                                size="sm"
                                startContent={<IconMinus size={16} />}
                              >
                                Remove option
                              </Button>
                              <Button
                                color="secondary"
                                variant="flat"
                                size="sm"
                                onClick={() => handleAddSubOption(optionIndex)}
                                className="mb-3"
                                startContent={<IconPlus size={16} />}
                              >
                                Add sub-option
                              </Button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        ))}
                        <Button
                          className="bg-deep-green text-white"
                          endContent={<IconPlus size={16} />}
                          onPress={() => handleAddOption()}
                        >
                          Add option
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    ) : (
                      <></>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                  <Button color="danger" variant="light" onPress={onClose}>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                  {addProduct.isLoading ? (
                    <Button
                      color="primary"
                      className="bg-black text-white"
                      disabled
                    >
                      <Spinner size="sm" color="default" />
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <Button
                      color="primary"
                      type="submit"
                      className="bg-deep-green text-white"
                    >
                      Add
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </ModalFooter>
              </>
            )}
          </ModalContent>
        </form>
      </Modal>
      <Toaster position="top-right" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-robinson-6rv498

How can I fix my current code to achieve the desired validation?

Cheers.